# Javascript smooth method chaining

Tags: javascript, methods, chaining

I have a webservice which can take certain parameters, like such, ?top=5&orderby=column --- etc...

I want to be able to execute my object like such:

```
var call = new API();
call.get().top(5).skip(15).orderby("address");
```

The challenge is to only have the last orderby trigger the execute() method. Here is my code. Please let me know if you have any better ideas! It's currently delaying by 25ms when each function ends, and stops the timer when the next function starts. Is this proper/acceptable?

---

```
var API = function (webservice) {
this.webservice(webservice);
return this;
};

API.prototype = {
version: function (urlFormat) {
    if (urlFormat) {
        return "v" + urlFormat.split('.').join('_');
    }
    return sessionStorage.getItem("version");
},
path: function () {
    return "../WebAPI/";
},
execute: function () {
    var path = this.path() + this.webservice() + ".svc/";
    if (this.__parameters) {
        path += "?";
    }
    var first = true;
    for (var k in this.__parameters) {
        if (k !== "type")
        path += ((first) ? (function(){first = false; return ""})() : "&") + "$" + k + "=" + this.__parameters[k];
    };
    console.log(this.__parameters.type + ": " + path);
    return this;
},
put: function () {
    this.doIt("type","put");
    return this;
},
post: function () {
    this.doIt("type","post");
    return this;
},
get: function() {
    this.doIt("type","get");
    return this;
},
delete: function() {
    this.doIt("type","delete");
    return this;
},
toString: function () {
    return "API";
},
webservice: function(webservice) {
    if (webservice) {
        this.__webservice = webservice;
    }
    else {
        return this.__webservice;
    }
},
top: function (p) {
    this.doIt("top",p);
    return this;
},
view: function (p) {
    this.doIt("view",p);
    return this;
},
orderby: function (p) {
    this.doIt("orderby",p);
    return this;
},
criteria: function (p) {
    this.doIt("criteria",p);
    return this;
},
skip: function (p) {
    this.doIt("skip",p);
    return this;
},
filter: function (p) {
    this.doIt("filter",p);
    return this;
},
doIt: function (method, parameter) {
    this.__timerStop();
    this.__parameters[method] = parameter;
    this.__timerStart();
},
__timerStop: function () {
    if (this.__timer) {
        clearTimeout(this.__timer);
    }
},
__timerStart: function (append) {
    var self = this;
    if (this.__timer) {
        this.__timerStop();
    }
    this.__timer = setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("executing.");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(self.__parameters));
        self.execute();
    }, 25);
},
__parameters: {}
};
```

Comment: I don't like the idea of magically executing. Either you execute after each method call, or else the programmer has to explicitly execute the call. I have never seen this delayed execution before and it gives me the creeps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**: You know what? I'm going to soften my stance on this one (original answer below). You should actually be OK given that the callback you're passing to `setTimeout` can never fire before your method chain is "complete" given JavaScript's single-threaded event loop. (And in fact, this also implies you should be safe passing `0` to `setTimeout` instead of `25`.)

I still think you're nuts for thinking up this design (and if this is code that multiple developers will be touching, I'd say you're better off with a simpler design just to lessen the risk of team confusion from undue complexity); but if you insist on taking this path, you actually *shouldn't* run into any weird Heisenbugs.

But yeah, I stand by my original advice about requiring the `execute` call explicitly.

---

Oh man. You are **crazy** to even be considering this! I mean, part of me does love you for it (I am a [big fan of horrifying hacks](http://philosopherdeveloper.wordpress.com/2012/03/16/the-littlest-ruby-debugger/)); but the fact is that taking this approach, while it *might* end up working, will drive you nuts if/when it goes haywire.

The main reason I would strongly discourage it is that the alternative is *very* easy and, more importantly, actually *reliable*: just establish the rule that `execute` is the method that actually sends the request, and so any chained method call must end with that:

```
call.get().top(5).skip(15).orderby("address").execute();
```

If you're seriously in love with this timer-based idea, something tells me you've never really suffered from a [Heisenbug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug) before (or, as I originally guessed, you're just out of your mind).

Comment: On top of that, the ``execute`` method could take a callback function that could be passed a ``results`` object, making it much easier for the user to specify *what* they want done when their query completes.

Comment: For what is worth you can reduce the setTimeout to 1 (not 0 - 0 = no delay and thus 2 requests) - as JS evaluates code "instaneously", thus 1ms is the delay for checking if another method exists in the chain. Though I must agree with the commenter above - is there a reason for not having execute function?

Comment: @eithed: I think you're mistaken about that. See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m3dqs/. You can see that even though `0` is passed to `setTimeout`, the callback function does not get executed synchronously; thus every iteration of the loop cancels the previous one.

Comment: @Dan Tao: Nifty! I've been using timeouts for so long, thus I've assumed what I've written. Cheers!

Comment: I love you, Thank you, and yes--- I am crazy.

Comment: My first thought was to make it event-driven, rather than callback driven.. But, that may change.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting idea. Although, why not do something like this instead:

```
call({ type: "get", top: 5, skip: 15, orderby: "address" });
```

Then process each argument by looping through the object inside your `call` implementation, then make the service request.

```
for(var arg in args) {
    if(args.hasOwnProperty(arg) && args.propertyIsEnumerable(arg)) {
        // process argument
    }
}
```

This keeps things simple.

Comment: an obvious reason - doing `call.get().top()` might do something different than `call.top().get()` - if you pass all attributes as one object you can't differentiate the behavior, but must code it in.

An example:
`Cow.Eat('grass').Poo()` is something different than `Cow.Poo().Eat('grass')`, as in first example Cow is empty, in second it's full of grass.